# JQuery ajax call to Graylog2 not working

Tags: jquery, graylog2

I have a web app and a graylog server. I want to send an ajax message to said Graylog server. The only example they provide is:

```
curl -XPOST http://graylog.example.org:12202/gelf -p0 -d '{"short_message":"Hello there", "host":"example.org", "facility":"test", "_foo":"bar"}'
```

That works just fine. However when I do this:

```
message = '{"host":"hostname","short_message":"short message","full_message":"longer message","facility":"dev"}';
                    console.log(message);
                    $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://X.X.X.X:12201/gelf',
                            method: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify(message),
                            success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR){
                                    console.log("SF Log posted with result: " + result);
                                    if ( $.isFunction( settings.callback ) ) {
                                            settings.callback.call( this );
                                    }
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                    console.log("SF Log encountered error: " + errorThrown);
                            },
                            complete: function(){
                                    console.log('on complete: ' , this.data);
                            }
                    });
```

The message is received in Graylog, but it refuses to process it. It just sits in the journal.

This is my current configuration from a plugin I'm writing so we can log in different areas. I've had crossDomain set to true and I've tried just using $.post, but my environment doesn't let me for some reason. Any ideas what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I found the problem 10 minutes later. Get rid of the JSON.stringify.